# Write a .txt file in C

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to write in a file in a certain format, but when I open the file in Notepad, it's not as I want. If I decrease the size of the window (for Notepad), it becomes became as I want, but if I maximize a little bit, the format changes.

My code to generate the file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    FILE *fp,*fp2;
    int i=0;
    int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10,num11,num12;
    fp=fopen("treino01.bin","r");
    fp2=fopen("treino02.txt","w");

    fprintf(fp2,"ESTC\tNDEP\tRENDA\tTIPOR\tVBEM\tNPARC\tVPARC\tTEL\tIDADE\tRESMS\tENTRADA\tCLASSE\n",num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,
                    num6,num7,num8,num9,num10,num11,num12);
    while( (fscanf(fp, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4, &num5, 
            &num6, &num7, &num8, &num9, &num10, &num11, &num12))!= EOF ){

        printf("%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\n",num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10,num11,num12);
        fprintf(fp2,"%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\t%d,\n",num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10,num11,num12);


    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

The first file file is like:

12 fields and each field is represented as a numbers, it's a table.

The second file is just read the first file and insert the comma after each number (1,).

What I need to do is just insert a comma after each number.

Comment: If I understand you, you want to do the same thing you're already doing, only that you would have it dynamically, with multiple numbers. Right?

Comment: Is your printf function printing the number's with comma correctly? is there any error?

Comment: If I understand you simply want comma separated values in the second file, then just remove the `\t` tabs. For example change your format string to `"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n"`

Comment: And use `==12` instead of `!=EOF` and remove all arguments except the first two from the first `fprintf`. Also, check the return value of `fopen`. It returns `NULL` on failure.

Comment: Is it a problem with line endings — you need, for some reason, to include `\r` before each `\n` because that isn't happening automatically?  Note that (notwithstanding the `.txt` suffix) you open both files without either `b` (binary) or `t` (text) in the flags.  Maybe the default is `b` binary, in which case the LF to CRLF mapping won't occur.

Comment: The problem is that the '\n' doesn't work to skip a line in the file....if i decrease the size of the windows(notepad) appears that is ok, but if i maximize, it's not ok, the second line fill the rest of the first line ans so on.

Comment: guys, thanks a lot, i just put '\r' before '\n' and now works :)

Answer (score 1):

Potential problem of line terminators on Windows. You can try this:

```
fp2 = fopen("treino02.txt", "wt");
```

Please note the "t" in the mode parameter.